# How can I exclude a branch pattern from default reviewer/approval rules in Bit Bucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, pull-request

We have a standard set of reviewers and require a specified number of approvals from 3 different groups that share a code repository.  Any code going into the develop branch of the shared repo needs to include the full list of reviewers and requires approval by 3 individuals from each of the 3 groups (9 total).  To accomplish this in Bit Bucket, we have 3 groups of reviewers and require 3 approvals from each group.  These rules apply to all branches and that part works great.

We have an exception, which only requires 3 total approvals and we are using a branch prefix (translations/) for those more trivial changes.  I can specify a different set of default reviewers with different approvals using that branch pattern, but the default requirement of 9 approvals is still being required by Bit Bucket before we can merge because it fits the any branch pattern on the 3 other requirements.

How can I configure Bit Bucket so the translations will a have a smaller set of reviewers and only require 3 approvals, but every other branch will include all reviewers and require 9 approvals (3 from each group).

Comment: How do you have the pattern(s) defined now?

Comment: @JimRedmond, the first 3 rules have no pattern.  The one for translations is using translations/.  I was trying to determine how I could create a pattern for the first 3 rules that would exclude 'translations/' but couldn't figure it out.